# Why do my meshes get duplicated?

Tags: shape-keys

I have a mesh with a shape key. Somehow at some point it gets duplicated, sometimes several times. The duplicated meshes get the same name as the original, except they get the phrase _SHAPE_KEYS attached to them, like baseMesh_SHAPE_KEYS, and baseMesh_SHAPE_KEYS_SHAPE_KEYS and so on. I keep deleting them, yet they come back.

Does anybody have an idea why is this happening? Or is this the way blender handles shape keys, I just failed to notice it until recently?

Comment: what do you mean by "at some point it gets duplicated" ? what operation were you doing when this happen ?

Comment: if you don't remember see your undo history with F3 , or take a look at the info panel when you see a duplicated mesh.

Comment: Last time this happened I had a human body mesh with teeth as a separate mesh. I realized that I don't need the inner parts of the mouth, because the set of teeth had that as well, so I proceeded to get rid of it. I hid the teeth, deleted the nonrequired vertices from my body mesh. When I unhid the teeth I got back two objects. One that I hid, and another with the name teeth_SHAPE_KEYS.
It seems like a feature rather than a bug, but if is I fail to understand its purpose, and I don't know how do I prevent Blender from doing what it does.